# Javascript Error: cannot read property 'getContext' of null with canvas tag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a canvas but I keep getting an error saying that it can't get the context of null at line 169, which is in my init() function. I created the var "canvas" at the beginning of the script and set it to my canvas tag using "canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")" but it still says it's null. This is for a school project due on Wednesday, and I'm terrible at painting with the canvas tag - please help :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

        <title>Emma Wood | Space Invaders II</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unlock" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="WebsiteImages/computer.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="SI2_StyleSheet.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //TO DO: health bar for alien doesn't work, show message for win or lose or forfeit @ end of game, create cool instructions (flash project(?)
            var canvas;
            var ctx;
            var WIDTH = 1000;
            var HEIGHT = 400;

            //variables for the avatar
            var dx = 5;
            var dy = 5;
            var x = 80;
            var xRight = 120;
            var y = 210;
            var yDown = 320;
            var OnOff = 1 * 1;
            var healthAvatar = 130;

            //variables for the invader
            var xCoord = 910;
            var xCoordRight = 950;
            var yCoord = 210;
            var yCoordDown = 320;
            var OnOff2 = 1 * 1;
            var healthInvader = 130;

            //variables for the bullets
            var bulletNumber = 0 * 1; // this is the number of the bullet that is being shot 
            var bulletX = new Array(100); // this is the x position of the bullet relative to its original position 
            var bulletY = new Array(100); // this is the y position of the bullet relative to its original position
            var bulletOnOff = new Array(100); // this determines whether or not the bullet is moving, 1 = up, 2 = left, 3 = down, 4 = right

            for (var z = 0; z < 100; z++)
            {
                bulletX[z] = 0; 
                bulletY[z] = 0; 
                bulletOnOff[z] = 0; 
            }

            init();

            function circle(x,y,r) 
                {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }


            function rect(x,y,w,h) 
                {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.stroke();
                }

            function clear() 
                {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                }

            function startTimer()
                {
                    var buttonName = document.getElementById("move").value;

                    if (buttonName == "Begin")
                    {

                        timer = setInterval("moveInvader()", 200);
                        document.getElementById("move").value = "Quit";
                        window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        endGame();
                    }
                }

            function moveBullet()
                {
                    for (var f = 0; f < 100; f++)
                    {
                        if (bulletOnOff[f] == 1)
                        {
                            //this moves the bullet up
                            bulletY[f] += 10;
                        }
                        else if (bulletOnOff[f] == 2)
                        {
                            //this moves the bullet left
                            bulletX[f] -= 10;
                        }
                        else if (bulletOnOff[f] == 3)
                        {
                            //this moves the bullet down
                            bulletY[f] -= 10;
                        }
                        else if (bulletOnOff[f] == 4)
                        {
                            //this moves the bullet right
                            bulletX[f] += 10;
                        }

                        //checks to see if the bullet is going outside the boundaries
                        if (bulletX[f] < 0 || bulletX[f] > 1000 || bulletY[f] < 0 || bulletY[f] > 400)
                        {
                            bulletOnOff[f] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    checkHealth();
                    draw();
                }

            function endGame()
                {
                    clear();
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    clearInterval(bulletTimer);
                    window.removeEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);

                    //clearing the bullets
                    for (var z = 0; z < 100; z++)
                    {
                        bulletX[z] = 0; 
                        bulletY[z] = 0; 
                        bulletOnOff[z] = 0; 
                    }
                    bulletNumber = 0;

                    //variables for the avatar
                    x = 80;
                    xRight = 120;
                    y = 210;
                    yDown = 320;
                    OnOff = 1 * 1;
                    healthAvatar = 130;

                    //variables for the invader
                    xCoord = 910;
                    xCoordRight = 950;
                    yCoord = 210;
                    yCoordDown = 320;
                    OnOff2 = 1 * 1;
                    healthInvader = 130;

                    document.getElementById("move").value = "Begin";
                    init();
                }

            function init() 
                {
                    bulletTimer = setInterval("moveBullet()", 200);
                    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    draw();
                    return 
                }

            function doKeyDown(evt)
                {
                    switch (evt.which) 
                    {
                        case 38:  

                        y -= dy;
                        yDown -= dy;
                        checkHealth();  

                        break;
                        case 40: 

                        y += dy;
                        yDown += dy;
                        checkHealth();

                        break;
                        case 37:  

                        x -= dx;
                        xRight -= dx;
                        OnOff = 2 * 1;
                        checkHealth();

                        break;
                        case 39: 

                        x += dx;
                        xRight += dx;
                        OnOff = 1 * 1;
                        checkHealth();

                        break;
                        case 83:

                        //fires the bullet up
                        if (OnOff == 1)
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x + 45; 
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x - 50;
                        }
                        bulletY[bulletNumber] = y - 20;

                        bulletOnOff[bulletNumber] = 1;

                        bulletNumber += 1;

                        if (bulletNumber == 100)
                        {
                            bulletNumber = 0;
                        }

                        break;
                        case 65:

                        //fires the bullet left
                        if (OnOff == 1)
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x + 45; 
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x - 50;
                        }

                        bulletY[bulletNumber] = y - 20;

                        bulletOnOff[bulletNumber] = 2;

                        bulletNumber += 1;

                        if (bulletNumber == 100)
                        {
                            bulletNumber = 0;
                        }

                        break;
                        case 87:

                        //fires the bullet down
                        if (OnOff == 1)
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x + 45; 
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x - 50;
                        }

                        bulletY[bulletNumber] = y - 20;

                        bulletOnOff[bulletNumber] = 3;

                        bulletNumber += 1;

                        if (bulletNumber == 100)
                        {
                            bulletNumber = 0;
                        }

                        break;
                        case 68:

                        //fires the bullet right
                        if (OnOff == 1)
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x + 45; 
                        }

                        else 
                        {
                            bulletX[bulletNumber] = x - 50;
                        }

                        bulletY[bulletNumber] = y - 20;

                        bulletOnOff[bulletNumber] = 4;

                        bulletNumber += 1;

                        if (bulletNumber == 100)
                        {
                            bulletNumber = 0;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    draw();
                }

            function checkHealth()
                {
                    //checks to see if the alien and avatar bump
                    if ( ( (x > xCoord && x < xCoordRight) || (xRight > xCoord && xRight < xCoordRight) ) && ( (y > yCoord && y < yCoordDown) || (yDown > yCoord && yDown < yCoordDown) ) )
                    {
                        healthAvatar -= 5;
                        if (healthAvatar == 0)
                        {
                            endGame();
                        }
                    }
                    //checks to see if the bullet hits the alien
                    for (var g = 0; g < 100; g++)
                    {
                        if ( ( (bulletX[g] > xCoord && bulletX[g] < xCoordRight) || ( (bulletX[g] + 5) > xCoord && (bulletX[g] + 5) < xCoordRight) ) && ( (bulletY[g] > yCoord && bulletY[g] < yCoordDown) || ((bulletY[g] + 5) > yCoord && (bulletY[g] + 5) < yCoordDown) ) )
                        {
                            healthInvader -= 5;
                            if (healthInvader == 0)
                            {
                                endGame();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    draw();
                }

            function draw() 
                {
                    clear();
                    //canvas background color
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    //outline of canvas
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
                    rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

                    //draws the bullets

                    for (var c = 0; c < 100; c++)
                    {
                        if (bulletOnOff[c] == 0)
                        {
                            //this makes the bullet follow the avatar
                            ctx.fillStyle = "#000CFF";
                            if (OnOff == 1)
                            {
                                ctx.fillRect((x + 45), (y - 20), 5, 5);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                ctx.fillRect((x - 50), (y - 20), 5, 5);
                            }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            //this makes the bullet move 
                            ctx.fillStyle = "#000CFF";
                            ctx.fillRect(bulletX[c], bulletY[c], 5, 5);
                        }
                    }

                    //draws the health bars

                    //red
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 350, 130, 30);
                    ctx.fillRect(850, 350, 130, 30);
                    //green
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#42FF00";
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 350, healthAvatar, 30);
                    ctx.fillRect(850, 350, healthInvader, 30);

                    //making the person 

                    //making the person (right)
                    if (OnOff == 1)
                    {
                        //draw circle for the face
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFEFC9";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle, anticlockwise
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw circles for the eye
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#FFFFFF";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, (y - 10), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, (y - 8), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw an arc for the smile
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, (y + 20), 10, 0, Math.PI, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw a rectangle for the body
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 20), (y + 30), 40, 50);

                        //draw rectangles for the legs
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 20), (y + 80), 10, 20);
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 10), (y + 80), 10, 20);

                        //draw rectangles for the arms
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFEFC9";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 40), (y + 30), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 20), (y + 30), 20, 10);

                        //draw rectangles for the feet
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 30), (y + 100), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 10), (y + 100), 20, 10);

                        //adding a lightsaber
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000CFF";
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 40), (y - 20), 10, 50);

                        //lightsaber handle
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 40), (y + 30), 10, 10);

                        //adding an eyebrow
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 10), (y - 20), 20, 2);
                    }
                    //making the person (left)
                    else
                    {
                        //draw circle for the face
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFEFC9";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle, anticlockwise
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw circles for the eye
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#FFFFFF";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, (y - 10), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, (y - 8), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw an arc for the smile
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(x, (y + 20), 10, 0, Math.PI, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw a rectangle for the body
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 20), (y + 30), 40, 50);

                        //draw rectangles for the legs
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 20), (y + 80), 10, 20);
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 10), (y + 80), 10, 20);

                        //draw rectangles for the arms
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFEFC9";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 40), (y + 30), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 20), (y + 30), 20, 10);

                        //draw rectangles for the feet
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 30), (y + 100), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((x + 10), (y + 100), 20, 10);

                        //adding a lightsaber
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000CFF";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 50), (y - 20), 10, 50);

                        //lightsaber handle
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 50), (y + 30), 10, 10);

                        //adding an eyebrow
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                        ctx.fillRect((x - 10), (y - 20), 20, 2);
                    }

                    //draws the invader

                    //making the invader (right)
                    if (OnOff2 == 1)
                    {
                        //draw circle for the face
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#83E25D";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, yCoord, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle, anticlockwise
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw rectangles and circles for the ears
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 20), (yCoord - 36), 5, 15);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 15), (yCoord - 36), 5, 15);

                        ctx.fillStyle = "#83E25D";
                        ctx.arc((xCoord - 18), (yCoord - 36), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.arc((xCoord + 18), (yCoord - 36), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw circles for the eye
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#FFFFFF";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, (yCoord - 10), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, (yCoord - 8), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw an arc for the smile
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, (yCoord + 20), 10, 0, Math.PI, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw a rectangle for the body
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 20), (yCoord + 30), 40, 50);

                        //draw rectangles for the legs
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 20), (yCoord + 80), 10, 20);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 10), (yCoord + 80), 10, 20);

                        //draw rectangles for the arms
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#83E25D";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 40), (yCoord + 30), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 20), (yCoord + 30), 20, 10);

                        //draw rectangles for the feet
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 30), (yCoord + 100), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 10), (yCoord + 100), 20, 10);

                        //adding a lightsaber
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 40), (yCoord - 20), 10, 50);

                        //lightsaber handle
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 40), (yCoord + 30), 10, 10);

                        //adding an eyebrow
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 10), (yCoord - 20), 20, 2);
                    }
                    //making the invader (left)
                    else
                    {
                        //draw circle for the face
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#83E25D";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, yCoord, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // x, y, radius, starting angle, ending angle, anticlockwise
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw rectangles and circles for the ears
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 20), (yCoord - 36), 5, 15);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 15), (yCoord - 36), 5, 15);

                        ctx.fillStyle = "#83E25D";
                        ctx.arc((xCoord - 18), (yCoord - 36), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.arc((xCoord + 18), (yCoord - 36), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw circles for the eye
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#FFFFFF";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, (yCoord - 10), 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, (yCoord - 8), 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw an arc for the smile
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000000";
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.arc(xCoord, (yCoord + 20), 10, 0, Math.PI, true); 
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();

                        //draw a rectangle for the body
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 20), (yCoord + 30), 40, 50);

                        //draw rectangles for the legs
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#5DD8E2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 20), (yCoord + 80), 10, 20);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 10), (yCoord + 80), 10, 20);

                        //draw rectangles for the arms
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#83E25D";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 40), (yCoord + 30), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 20), (yCoord + 30), 20, 10);

                        //draw rectangles for the feet
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 30), (yCoord + 100), 20, 10);
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord + 10), (yCoord + 100), 20, 10);

                        //adding a lightsaber
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 50), (yCoord - 20), 10, 50);

                        //lightsaber handle
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#B4B2B2";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 50), (yCoord + 30), 10, 10);

                        //adding an eyebrow
                        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
                        ctx.fillRect((xCoord - 10), (yCoord - 20), 20, 2);
                    }
                }
            function moveInvader()
                {

                    if (x < xCoord)
                        {
                            xCoord -= 10;
                            xCoordRight -= 10;
                            OnOff2 = 2 * 1;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            xCoord += 10;
                            xCoordRight += 10;
                            OnOff2 = 1 * 1;
                        }
                    if (y < yCoord)
                        {
                            yCoord -= 10;
                            yCoordDown -= 10;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            yCoord += 10;
                            yCoordDown += 10;
                        }
                    draw();
                    checkHealth();
                }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()" style="background-color: black; color: white; font-family: 'Unlock', cursive; font-size: 50px; text-align: center;">
        Space Invaders Returns
        </br>
        </br>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="400">
        This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
        </canvas>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input id="move" type="button" name="Move" value="Begin" onclick="startTimer()" style="color: black; font-family: 'Unlock', cursive; font-size: 50px;"/>
        </br>
        </br>
        <div id="thisDiv" class="hiddenContent">
            Game over. 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 704 lines of code is a *lot* - best to trim it down to a [MCVE] -

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because the script is before the body of your html. Thus, the script loads and runs before the actual html DOM loads and it cannot find the canvas element since it does not exist yet.

**Change the order of your html syntax, by putting the script at the end of your  element.**

```
<body>
   ......
   <script>YOUR SCRIPT</script>
</body>
```